# Unable to access Visual FoxPro database through MS Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, visual-foxpro

I am trying to access a Visual FoxPro Database through MS Access 2013 on a Windows 7 Machine, but I am getting this error.

"specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 0. The operation completed successfully(Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver C:\Windows\system32\vfpodbc.dll).(#160)"

I tried installing Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro 9.0 SP2 but I am getting the same results.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you. I could do a system restore and finally I am able to import data via Access.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use OLEDB with Access, can you? If you can then it is straight forward with VFPOLEDB driver.

You cannot use VFP ODBC driver if database version is later than VFP6.

If you are in a need to downgrade to access (which I never classify as a "database") then you could use Excel in between. Excel can import data using OLEDB (but strangely access can't, go figure). Or if you know how to write VBA code in access then maybe you could utilize the OLEBD driver from there too.

Another option might be to get the data to SQL server express via OleDb, then from SQL server to access (yet a bigger downgrade).

Another option would be to use code for this. If it were from VFP it would be as easy as 1,2,3 creating a cursor adapter or remote view to access and pumping data there. With C# too you can create connections to both sides, read from one and write to the other.

If I were you, I wouldn't choose to downgrade to access, but maybe upgrade to postgreSQL, MS SQL, ...

PS: Check out Advantage Database Server. It was supporting ODBC for VFP (local server version for free). That might be your option.

PS2: Access can import XML, right? Maybe you would want to export VFP data as XML and import from there.

Comment: Thank you. I did a system restore and finally imported data via MS Access.